# Foreach Urls JSON Decode

Tags: php, json

`$urlsDB` is a variable containing JSON.

```
print_r($urlsDB );
```

outputs:

```
[\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/LOGO-SEG-2.png\",\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/algoritims.jpg\"]
```

How do I create the `foreach` using `json_decode` correctly?

```
   <?php
    $urls = json_decode($urlsDB , true);

    if ($urls != '' ) { 

            foreach ($urls as $url) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail " />

    <?php
     }
    }

    ?>
```

`Var_dump($urls);` returns empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stripping the slashes before the `json_decode()`

```
$input = '[\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/LOGO-SEG-2.png\",\"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/algoritims.jpg\"]';

$json = json_decode(stripslashes($input),true);
```

the output of `var_dump($json)` gives me the following

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(64) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/LOGO-SEG-2.png"
    [1]=> string(64) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/algoritims.jpg"
}
```

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de50d5efd85618e219e4b6c0eb333662d0352301)!

---

Edit to add:

the original string is really a string representation of a json array, and not an object since it has no keys. I tried that same fix on an object with a `url` key on each element and this is is the result.

```
$input = '[{\"url\" : \"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/LOGO-SEG-2.png\"},{\"url\" : \"http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/algoritims.jpg\"}]';

$json = json_decode(stripslashes($input),true);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        ["url"]=> string(64) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/LOGO-SEG-2.png"
    }
    [1]=> array(1) {
        ["url"]=> string(64) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/algoritims.jpg"
    }
}
```

Additionally, `\"` is *not* a valid json character in a string literal. It is only valid if the variable is declared using `"` (ex: `$encoded = "{\"some value\"}";`).

```
echo var_dump(json_decode('{\"myKey\": \"myValue\"}', true)); // output: NULL
```

Try it [live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50f389239ed3c025a3759ec6d6472bb7cf3d3f96).

Comment: This is treating the symptom, not the cause. Also, it will break when the any element contains double quotes.

Comment: @ishegg I disagree: the reason `json_decode()` doesn't work is because of the backslashes (proof: the only difference between the string in your answer an OP's is the presence of backslashes) also, we don't know where OP is getting this data from, for all we know s/he may have no control over the input value

Comment: It absolutely is because of the backslashes. But the problem is that `\"` is a valid string in a JSON object. So, if you strip them out, you *will* have problems in the future (i.e., the URL comes with a text description, which might perfectly have quotes in it). Look [here](https://3v4l.org/1gqSB). Perfectly valid strings, but the code breaks because of `stripslashes()`ing the JSON encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting invalid JSON. You have escaped quotes at the beginning and end. This is valid:

```
["http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/LOGO-SEG-2.png","http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/algoritims.jpg"]
```

Maybe you're applying some filter to the database before processing it?

This should be working:

```
<?php
$a = '["http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/LOGO-SEG-2.png","http:\\/\\/localhost\\/theme\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2017\\/08\\/algoritims.jpg"]
';
$urls = json_decode($a, true);
if (count($urls) > 0) {
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail " />
    <?php
    }
}
```

You shouldn't `htmlspecialchars()` the JSON encoded string. That will escape the quotes, making the JSON object invalid. What you should do is `htmlspecialchars()` every element in the array separately, preferably at the moment of display, not at the moment of saving it (read [here](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/)).

Comment: Before saving I used `htmlspecialchars`, because I was not able to save an array in input, so I converted the array into JSON

Comment: You used htmlspecialchars() **after** encoding to JSON? You should do it before encoding, then encode. You shouldn't have any problems then. Or, even better, don't do it at all until after you decode, when printing each element.

Comment: an even better solution would be to not use htmlspecialchars at all. you do that just before *displaying* stuff, not for saving

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Agreed! I wrote something just like that a few minutes ago, check out the edited answer.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I've tried several different ways to save the array in the input, but I was not saving, the only way I could have been using `htmlspecialchars()` before saving and then using the `stripslashes` in the foreach

Comment: @Gislef I'm almost 100% certain that is because you are not using modern parameterized queries. Learn about PDO, read [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). There is literally no excuse for having to resort to such ancient ways to save content ;)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I like to learn about PDO, I'm still newbie, but in this case I'm using wordpress and creating a theme, I searched for functions and wordpress hooks and I did not find the solution, I just managed to solve it this way. But soon I believe I will improve my ability to program

Comment: @Gislef careful there, you'll blink twice and this will become an habit. Most of the times the hard, long way is the best way. Especially when you're first learning. (This maybe sounds condescending, it isn't! Just talking from experience :) )

Comment: @ishegg Yes, I understand it as a great orientation and I agree with you :) Thank you so much